# Magnific-popup gallery is showing display none elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magnific-popup, mixitup

I'm having troubles in a project where i need to use magnific-popup in combo with mixitup.
I have a grid of clickable items that starts a magnific-popup gallery if u click on them, the problem pop out when i filter those items using mixitup (mixitup adds css display property in line on the elements).

Substantially, after i've filtered some items, magnific-popup gallery still include the display none elements and i do not want this to happen.

Here's an example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrzgpN

```
function mfp_init() {
 $('section .gallery').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a',
  type: 'image',
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
  gallery: {
   enabled: true
  }    
 });
}

// Mix it Up init
$(function(){
 $('section .gallery').mixItUp();
 $('section .gallery').on('mixEnd', function(){      
  mfp_init()
 });
});
```

In the example, i tried to call magnific-popup only when mixitup ended the filtering, but it still detect the display none elements and put them into the gallery.

Sorry for my bad english, hope it sounds clear. Thanks for the help!

Cheers,
Michele

Comment: You just want section .mix{display: none;} from your css to work?

Comment: .mix{display: none;} is actually working, the problem is when u filter the elements and magnific popup still includes in gallery the display:none elements.

Comment: @Malander did you find an answer for this?